# where do I use the toolboxes?

Tags: matlab, dependencies

I'm working on a scientific application which is now over 10 years in development by multiple people.

Recently, we found out that our application requires multiple toolboxes, which are not part of the default MATLAB installation.
Since we are developing it with a University license, we have access to all toolboxes and therefore we never noticed this so far. 
However, we want to reduce the number of toolboxes to a minimum to make it easier and cheaper for other groups to use our software.

when I run

```
[fList,pList] = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('myFile.m')
```

`pList` list a couple of toolboxes like:

```
 NAME                                  Version  id  Certain
'MATLAB'                                 '9.4'  1   true
'Robust Control Toolbox'               '6.4.1'  5   true
'Mapping Toolbox'                        '4.6'  11  true
'Financial Toolbox'                     '5.11'  30  true
'Aerospace Toolbox'                     '2.21'  108 true
'Parallel Computing Toolbox'            '6.12'  80  false
'MATLAB Distributed Computing Server'   '6.12'  94  false
```

I'm sure that at least 'Finacial Toolbox' and 'Aerospace Toolbox' are not really required and we only use it through copy-pasting of online solutions into our software without thinking.

For example, we are using a function called `degrees2dms` which is part of a toolbox and simply converts decimal degrees into degrees, minutes and seconds. This could easily be implemented by our self without the use of additional toolboxes.

**My question is now the following:**

I know which toolboxes are used from `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`. How can I find out which functions from these toolboxes are used to replace those functions with our own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through the `fList` output: it's the list of your own MATLAB program files required to run `myFile.m`. Loop through them and for each one, run `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts` to find out which product(s) is/are required for each file in the code base. That will help you to narrow down which files to focus on.

You can also try to run the [dependency report](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html#f9-16299) on your code, that might provide a nicer interface for you to explore which file(s) use which toolbox(es).

Comment: This is a good idea and certainly helps to narrow down the problem. However, I hope there is an alternative since some of our functions are 1000 lines long...

Comment: The dependency report will tell you which file/function from each toolbox is called by each file in your code base. You can then do a search in the text editor for that function and replace it with one that does not require a toolbox

Comment: Yes, the dependency report does the trick. It is a bit time consuming since there are many different folders but I think I can manage it.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not totally automatic**, and uses the **semi-documented** function [`getcalliinfo`](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/function-definition-meta-info/#getcallinfo), but perhaps it may help.

From `help getcallinfo`:

```
GETCALLINFO  Returns called functions and their first and last lines
    This function is unsupported and might change or be removed without
    notice in a future version.
```

Consider this example function, which uses several toolboxes and contains a local function:

```
function y = example(x)
a = sinc(2);
b = example_local_function(pi);
c = @xcorr;
d = c([1 2 3], [4 5 6]);
y = imdilate(x,[1 1; 1 1]);
end

function z = example_local_fun(t)
z = t.^2 + exprnd(1);
end
```

Saving this function to file `example.m` and running `getcallinfo` gives

```
>> getcallinfo('example.m')
Name                 Type                 Starts Ends Length Full Name           
----                 ----                 ------ ---- ------ ---------           
example              function                1     7      7 example             
example_local_fun    subfunction             9    11      3 example>example_local_fun
ans = 
  1×2 struct array with fields:
    type
    name
    fullname
    functionPrefix
    calls
    firstline
    lastline
    linemask
```

The result is a struct array with two entries: the first for the main function and the second for the local function. Observe the first entry:

```
>> t(1)
ans = 
  struct with fields:

              type: [1×1 internal.matlab.codetools.reports.matlabType.Function]
              name: 'example'
          fullname: 'example'
    functionPrefix: 'example>'
             calls: [1×1 struct]
         firstline: 1
          lastline: 7
          linemask: [11×1 logical]
```

The called functions are in

```
>> t(1).calls
ans = 
  struct with fields:

      fcnCalls: [1×1 struct]
    innerCalls: [1×1 struct]
      dotCalls: [1×1 struct]
       atCalls: [1×1 struct]
```

Specifically, in this case the only two non-empty structs are

```
>> t(1).calls.fcnCalls
ans = 
  struct with fields:    
    names: {'sinc'  'example_local_function'  'pi'  'imdilate'}
    lines: [2 3 3 6]

>> t(1).calls.atCalls
ans = 
  struct with fields:    
    names: {'xcorr'}
    lines: 4
```

To see where the called functions are defined you can apply `which` to each of the cells in the cell array contained in the field `names`:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\toolbox\signal\signal\sinc.m
'example_local_function' not found.
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\toolbox\matlab\elmat\pi)
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\toolbox\images\images\imdilate.m
```

To automate the process you need to know the **name of the toolbox folder** (this is easily seen from your Matlab installation). For example, it is `'images'` for the Image Processing Toolbox (or you may prefer to use the full path to avoid false positives):

```
>> s = cellfun(@which, t(1).calls.fcnCalls.names, 'UniformOutput', false);
>> ind = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(s, 'images', 'once'));
>> t(1).calls.fcnCalls.names(ind)
>> t(1).calls.fcnCalls.names(ind)
ans =
  1×1 cell array
    {'imdilate'}
```

The procedure is the same for other toolboxes. For example, the folder of the Signal Processing Toolbox is called `'signals'`:

```
>> s = cellfun(@which, t(1).calls.fcnCalls.names, 'UniformOutput', false);
>> ind = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(s, 'signal', 'once'));
>> t(1).calls.fcnCalls.names(ind)
ans =
  1×1 cell array
    {'sinc'}
```

Similarly, for other types of calls:

```
>> s = cellfun(@which, t(1).calls.atCalls.names, 'UniformOutput', false);
>> ind = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(s, 'signal', 'once'));
>> t(1).calls.atCalls.names(ind)
ans =
  1×1 cell array
    {'xcorr'}
```

Or for the local function:

```
>> s = cellfun(@which, t(2).calls.fcnCalls.names, 'UniformOutput', false)
>> ind = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(s, 'stats', 'once'));
>> t(2).calls.fcnCalls.names(ind)
ans =
  1×1 cell array
    {'exprnd'}
```